# Draw arc with bezierCurveTo with relative coordinates for the arc points

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm not sure I am even asking this right. This is for a floor plan drawing thing, and right now I have lines with movable points on each end so the canvas is interactive. I want to use a curve to create a doorway arc to be drawn following that line. I have the start and end point from the existing code where to start and end the curve, but arc controls are to a specific coordinate that isnt computed so the arc never goes where it should.

This is what I have right now, I learned that the moveTo() and lineTo() is what is controlling its start and end point. Thanks for the help, I've never played with canvases before

```
activeLineDrawing.beginPath();
activeLineDrawing.moveTo(lineSegments[lineSeg].panels[i].getX2(),lineSegments[lineSeg].panels[i].getY2());
activeLineDrawing.lineTo(lineSegments[lineSeg].panels[i].getX1(),lineSegments[lineSeg].panels[i].getY1());
activeLineDrawing.bezierCurveTo(100, 75, 50, 1, lineSegments[lineSeg].panels[i].getX2(),lineSegments[lineSeg].panels[i].getY2());
activeLineDrawing.fillStyle = 'lightgrey';
activeLineDrawing.strokeStyle = 'lightgrey';
activeLineDrawing.stroke();
activeLineDrawing.closePath();
```

Comment: Did you try with the arc like I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Hey sorry! thanks for the answer it helped me a lot but still struggling a little here. this gives me the correct shape assuming a horizontal line between points, but since my starting points and end points are at a variable location, so it could be at any angle and the drawn gate will stay put and look weird. I am trying to play around with the rotate function but its a struggle.

Comment: I made some changes to my answer... move the code to function and drawing a diagonal door opening... You just have to play with the start end angles

Comment: If you have more complex scenarios, please create a proper snippet reproducing your issue.

Comment: I guess that last version did it for you...

Comment: Hi Thanks, actually I didnt try yet, but I looked at your answer and it made logical sense to me, so I think this will work, I'll post back after to share the working solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a regular arc, here is a sample code

```js
function drawDoor(ctx, color, sx, sy, ex, ey, offset) {
  var mx = (sx + (sx + ex) / 2) /2
  var my = (sy + (sy + ey) / 2) /2
  var iniAng = Math.atan2(ey-sy, ex-sx)/Math.PI - offset;
  var endAng = (iniAng + offset);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(sx, sy);  
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.lineTo(mx, my);  
  ctx.arc(mx, my, 45, iniAng * Math.PI, endAng * Math.PI, offset<0);
  ctx.lineTo(ex, ey);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var activeLineDrawing = canvas.getContext("2d");


// Door opening to the left
drawDoor(activeLineDrawing, "black", 180, 60, 270, 60, 0.5);

// Door opening to the right
drawDoor(activeLineDrawing, "red", 200, 100, 290, 100, -0.5);

// Diagonal door opening right
drawDoor(activeLineDrawing, "blue", 20, 20, 75, 80, -0.5);

// Diagonal door opening left
drawDoor(activeLineDrawing, "green", 50, 30, 140, 90, 0.5);

// Closet doors double opening
drawDoor(activeLineDrawing, "cyan", 145, 30, 145, 90, 0.25);
drawDoor(activeLineDrawing, "cyan", 145, 150, 145, 90, -0.25);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

My recommendation spend some time reading and understanding the math behind what I'm doing here, the same could be applied in many other places.